# :before and :after not working in IE8 despite setting DOCTYPE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dhtml, css

the W3C sites says that so long as you set DOCTYPE then the :before and :after should work. On their site in the 'Try It' for this it works with IE8, but when I try to use it (I checked by editing the example to the exact tags I'm using), it simply does not work.
    `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
is what I'm declaring.